# Why is my code for checking if a BST tree is AVL wrong?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

Hi I wrote this code that checks if a given BST is AVL or not, and in my mind it works but in the test it doesn't. 
The structure is a classic BST, with an integer, left and right.

```
bool AbsoluteDifference(int a, int b)
{
return ((a-b) <= 1)) ||(b-a) <= 1)); 
} 

 void aux_avl (BST b , int &l_var, bool &isAVL)
{
if (b == NULL)
  l_var--;  
  //In consecuence of not asking if the left or right is NULL or not
  //when I make the recursive call, if it is I have to decrease the value
else if (isAVL == true)//I don't want to keep checking if I already know that it's not AVL

{

   int l_left = l_var + 1;
   aux_avl(b->left,l_left,isAVL);

   int l_right = l_var +1;
   aux_avl(b->right, l_right,isAVL); 

   isAVL = AbsoluteDifference(l_left,l_right);

   lvar = max(l_left,l_right);
}
}

bool is_AVL(BST b)
{
   if (b == NULL)
      return true;
   else
  {
     int l_var =0;
     bool isAVL = true;
     auxavl(b,l_var,isAVL);

     return isAVL;
  }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read this next https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: The code compiles and works with a lot of trees, but there are some cases (unknown to me because I don't make the test) that it does fail

Comment: I'm sure that article is able to help you with that too.

Comment: What behavior do you expect from `AbsoluteDifference`?  You may be surprised to know it will always return 1 no matter what arguments you supply...  Except perhaps when integer overflow occurs.

Comment: My mistake, it's supposed to be a Boolean function

Comment: Yet it still serves no purpose.  You may as well just say `avl = 1`.  I also suggest you supply code that compiles, when asking a question.